# Getting click on embedded Youtube player div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `div` that uses jQuery to expand / contract on a click. This works great for images but fails for embedded Youtube videos. Is there any way to get a click on a `div` that contains a video so that I might change the dimensions of the `div`?

Note: I intend to use this only to expand the `div`: once the `div` is expanded I will let the clicks to the `div` be caught by the Flash player as so not to interfere with the video controls.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dotancohen/6B3Ay/). Note how difficult it is to click on the `div` containing the video in order to expand it.

Comment: youtube vidoe should be iframe which means you can't access inner DOM of iframe according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

so you should probably load youtube iframe manually using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/aZvqN/

see if you want something similar.

if not, you will have to setup a jsfiddle to help us help you :)

Comment: Thank you RASG! I have edited the question with an example fiddle.